# Any freebsd/PfSense realtime bandwidth monitoring tool?

Tags: bandwidth, bandwidth-control, freebsd

i need to know if there is any Tool (specifically for FreeBSD) , through which i can get the Realtime network traffic usage of any Host/IP , and which should also run on Multiple interfaces as well?
i have tried ntop, but its of no use.
tried iftop, but it does not supports merging of multiple interfaces.
any other tool to accomplish this task?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `systat -ifstat 1` will work for you.

Comment: This will only give the aggregate bandwidth used by each network device (interface) - it doesn't give a host breakdown.

Comment: Is it possible to to make `systat` show data as CSV (comma separated values) for scripting, Jrm?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  I don't see anything in systat(1).

Answer (score 3):

When you say ntop is no use -is that because you had problems using ntop, or that it didn't give you sufficient info?

You could install the pfflowd package which is a netflow emitter - I only played around with it a little and found some netflow collectors didn't seem to like it as it didn't totally conform to standards.

This thread http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=11185.0 mentions people being happy with Manage Engine's Netflow Analyzer Pro although the thread also mentions the free version only supports one interface. (and you need to run this on a box external to your pfsense)

Also if you are at the console or can ssh in, pftop gives real time info, and according to this thread http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php/topic,11289.0.html the bandwidthd package can also give per ip info.

Comment: If you really need per-IP/per-subnet breakdowns a netflow emitter is really what you need. (You don't *need* the `pfflowd` package, though it's pretty friendly compared to the alternative, [ng_netflow](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ng_netflow&sektion=4&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE) from the built-in netgraph tools.  You ***will*** need a netflow collector like flow-tools and a netflow "cruncher" like jkflow to analyze the data...)

Answer (score 0):

I use jnettop on my Linux boxes. It is based on libpcap, so it should work on BSD.